# How to delete MS Word document pages using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a list of pages that I want to delete in MS Word such as Page number : 5 to 10 , 12 to 16 etc. through MS Excel VBA.
I found a code to delete continuous pages through MS Excel VBA but when I run it gives ***"The Requested member of the collection does not exist" error."*** How can it be resolved ?

```
Sub DeletePages()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document

' Open the Word document
Set WordApp = New Word.Application
Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\mydocument.docx")

' Delete pages 3 to 5
myDoc.Range(Start:=myDoc.Bookmarks("Page3").Range.Start, _
            End:=myDoc.Bookmarks("Page5").Range.End).Delete

'Unbind
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, i As Long
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\mydocument.docx", AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    For i = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) To 1 Step -1
      Select Case i
        Case 5 To 10, 12 To 16
          .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i).GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").Delete
      End Select
    Next
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

To understand why you don't need to create any bookmarks - and to understand what the code is doing - see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks

Comment: "The Requested member of the collection does not exist" error." - I found out this error was caused due to not creating the bookmark in microsoft word. Is there a way to delete pages without creating a bookmark on document ?

Comment: «Is there a way to delete pages without creating a bookmark on document ?» Did you at least try the code I posted? You don't need to create any bookmarks for it to work.

Comment: I did. It gave me "Automation Error. The remote procedure call failed".Also when i press debug and hover my mouse over ```Name``` it gives me <Object Variable or with block variable not set> error.

Comment: That is most likely because you supplied an incorrect filename and/or file path. Either that or you have an orphaned Word session running - check via Task Manager. **PS:** I tested the coed and know it works. To understand why you don't need to create any bookmarks - and to understand what the code is doing - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks